# Using Google Contacts API with titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium

I am new to titanium and am trying to make a directory of contacts using Google Contact API.  I have read up on it yet aren't seeing too many helpful examples. I know I need authentication yet I can't seem to figure out where to start.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may know some of this already but here's the broad strokes overview for others and an answer to your question (Any help is appreciated).

You need to create an (Google) account and register your project/application first in order to make requests for non-public user data. The request must include an access token. The token also identifies your application to Google.

In order to authenticate a user/application: 
You will need to [Use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. You must register your project in the Google API Console and enable the Contacts API service in order to use OAuth 2.0.](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#authorizing_requests_to_the_api_name_service)

To implement the OAuth protocol in a Titanium app you can follow along with the sample/tutorial in this blog post:
**[OAuth Login for Titanium](https://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/10/oauth-login-for-titanium/)**